Macro delete multiple rows selected text and date
I'm looking for a macro that is formulated to search rows and select specific text in column A for deletion that contain the text "Summary", "Contract", "Amount", "Total Contract", "Less", if the cell is blank, and any date and time stamp on the report.  Only in Column A.
I did try to locate any previous related topics posted, but not much luck there. I did find a few similar ones.
Module 1 both had errors. I am pretty green at this.
Sub Delete_Rows ()  

 cells.Select  
 if cell. value "job" then  
 inputRange.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete  
 Exit For  
 Next Cell  
 or  
 Sub Delete_Rows()  

Dim ws As Worksheet  
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row)

For i = rng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Summary" Then
rng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i

End Sub

or
For R= 1 to sheet1.usedRange.Rows.Count
If Cells (r,"summary) = "0" then
Sheet1.Rows (r).EntireRow.Delete
End if


Have you attempted to compile the VBA code? It contains several syntax errors. For example, in the statement if cell.value "job" then, there is a missing =. Additionaly, select specific text in column A for deletion  It's not necessary to select it before deleting.
How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

"any date and time stamp on the report" please add some sample data so we can see what you're dealing with.

Run this code in debug mode. Look at what is happening on the sheet. Note how the values ​​of the variables change. I think it will push you in the right direction.
Sub Delete_Rows()

Cells.Clear
[A1] = "Heading":  [A1].Font.Bold = True: [A1].HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
[A2] = "Summary"
[A3] = "Summary"
[A4] = "Other"
[A5] = "Summary"
[A6] = "Other"

FirstLine = 2
LastLine = Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
DeletedLines = 0
Line = FirstLine
Criterion = "Summary"

Do While Line <= (LastLine - DeletedLines) '

If Cells(Line, 1) = Criterion Then
Rows(Line).EntireRow.Delete
DeletedLines = DeletedLines + 1
Else
Line = Line + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub

You can create multiple criteria. For example:
Criterion1 = "Summary"
Criterion2 = "job"
Criterion3 = "" ' This is an empty cell
Criterion4 = Empty ' This is an empty cell

Then compare the value of the cell as follows:
ValueOfThisCell = Cells(Line, 1)
If ValueOfThisCell = Criterion1 Or ValueOfThisCell = Criterion2 Or ValueOfThisCell = Criterion3 Or ValueOfThisCell = Criterion4 Then

Then the macro will be like this:
Sub Delete_Rows2()

Cells.Clear
[A1] = "Heading":  [A1].Font.Bold = True: [A1].HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
[A2] = "Summary"
[A3] = "Summary"
[A4] = "Other"
[A5] = "Summary"
[A6] = "Other"
[A7] = "job"
[A8] = ""
[A10] = "job"

FirstLine = 2
LastLine = Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
DeletedLines = 0
Line = FirstLine

Criterion1 = "Summary"
Criterion2 = "job"
Criterion3 = "" ' This is an empty cell
Criterion4 = Empty ' This is an empty cell

Do While Line <= (LastLine - DeletedLines) '
ValueOfThisCell = Cells(Line, 1)
If ValueOfThisCell = Criterion1 Or ValueOfThisCell = Criterion2 Or ValueOfThisCell = Criterion3 Or ValueOfThisCell = Criterion4 Then
Rows(Line).EntireRow.Delete
DeletedLines = DeletedLines + 1
Else
Line = Line + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub


Hi
Thank you so much for the prompt reply.
I may forgot to mention that the headers repeat themselves throughout the report. Unfortunately, they never show in the same row numbers.  I can pull a report and depending on the data lengths have from 7 to 10 headers reappear on various row numbers.

The last macro deleted all the data laving three rows, 2 of them stated other

I recommend you to study these macros in debug mode. See what happens on the sheet. Once you understand how these macros work, you can modify them to suit your needs. There are several ways to find the headers. I can't see your data, so I can't give you any advice.

You need to get the row number and column number of the header. The easiest way to do this is to click on the cell with the mouse.
Let's add two new variables to the Delete_Rows 2 macro: RowThisHeader and ColumnThisHeader. With their help, we will get the coordinates of the active cell.
RowThisHeader = ActiveCell.Row
ColumnThisHeader = ActiveCell.Column

Then the macro will look like this:
Sub Delete_Rows3()

Cells.Clear
[A1] = "Heading":  [A1].Font.Bold = True: [A1].HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
[A2] = "Summary"
[A3] = "Summary"
[A4] = "Other"
[A5] = "Summary"
[A6] = "Other"
[A7] = "job"
[A8] = ""
[A10] = "job"

[A1].Select

RowThisHeader = ActiveCell.Row
ColumnThisHeader = ActiveCell.Column


FirstLine = RowThisHeader + 1
LastLine = Cells(1000000, ColumnThisHeader).End(xlUp).Row
DeletedLines = 0
Line = FirstLine

Criterion1 = "Summary"
Criterion2 = "job"
Criterion3 = "" ' This is an empty cell
Criterion4 = Empty ' This is an empty cell

Do While Line <= (LastLine - DeletedLines) '
ValueOfThisCell = Cells(Line, ColumnThisHeader)
If ValueOfThisCell = Criterion1 Or ValueOfThisCell = Criterion2 Or ValueOfThisCell = Criterion3 Or ValueOfThisCell = Criterion4 Then
Rows(Line).EntireRow.Delete
DeletedLines = DeletedLines + 1
Else
Line = Line + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub


Is there a way I can share the spreadsheet. I was able to keep the header line, but all the data disappeared as well.

I was able to get it to work. However, it is deleting one row of data when I run the data macro script.

I did find a script that worked. However, it still deleted one row of data. Can I share my file with you?
